# Resources to find the "best" algorithm for a problem?

Tags: soft-question

There are many question that pose a none obscure problem and ask for the "best" algorithm, whatever "best" means.

For example, [Given a graph, decide if its edge connectivity is at least n/2 or not](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8093/given-a-graph-decide-if-its-edge-connectivity-is-at-least-n-2-or-not),

The normal process is to search the literature with every single name of the problem, and find a recent paper. Usually the "best" result will be the one of the references. A more recent approach is to ask the question here.

Are there websites specifically dedicated with information like this? A database of problems and list of algorithms with their complexities? I am imagining an OEIS for problems instead of integer sequences.

Comment: See [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/compendium-of-the-best-approximation-and-hardness-results-for-np-optimization-pro), I think this should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I was not aware of that post. The answers do indicate no satisfactory resource exists. This should be closed.

Comment: I agree that this question is a duplicate in spirit. However, this question is amore general than the linked one; in title at least. Although [this answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/compendium-of-the-best-approximation-and-hardness-results-for-np-optimization-pro/7974#7974) would answer this more general question, the other answers are specific to NP-hardness results and/or are discussions. Thus it would be a little awkward to close it as "exact duplicate", no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an attempt to build such a resource. It's called the [Complexity Garden](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Garden) and is "the botanical companion to the Complexity Zoo". Also see [this meta discussion](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1299/is-there-any-way-to-spread-an-announcement).